# How to change filter context for a slicer based on a condition Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I know what I want to do, but do not know how to accomplish it. The goal is to use more than one relationship for a slicer. In this situation everything uses a given date but there is an exception where I want to use a different date for filtering if a condition is met. I have detailed it below...

I have a date table in my power bi model, where my slicer uses the Date field.

| Date |
| --- |
| 01/01/2023 |
| 01/02/2023 |
| 01/03/2023 |
| 01/04/2023 |
| 01/05/2023 |

The other table I have is

| Event | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| B | 01/01/2023 | 01/11/2023 |
| C | 01/01/2023 | 01/05/2023 |

The active relationship is Start Date -- Date between the two tables. However, for event C I want to use the relationship End Date --- Date instead. For the date slicer in my report.

So, If I select the Date 01/01/2023 in my slicer my table would look like this

| Event | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| B | 01/01/2023 | 01/11/2023 |

Conversely if I selected 01/05/2023 the table would look like this

| Event | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 01/01/2023 | 01/05/2023 |